# Virtual method table of non-pointer object?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, vtable

If you have an object of a class that has virtual functions, and this object is not a pointer, will the virtual method table be used?

E.g let's pretend that the class `Student` has a virtual function `GetGrade()`. Since `my_student` is not a pointer to the polymorphic class, will virtual method tables be used?

```
Student my_student{};

my_student.GetGrade();
```

I was expecting the vtable to be consulted when I tried this, but it didn't happen.

Comment: Instead of describing some code, please show us a [mre]. And please elaborate more on your problem.

Comment: VMT is not a common acronym, it is more often referred to as the vtable. And no dynamic polymorphism/vtable is only used with pointer types (raw pointers, std::unique_ptr/std::shared_ptr) and references to a base class

Comment: Is student even derived from anything with a virtual function?

Comment: Whether the function call uses the vtable is more a question of whether the compiler can tell if the target function is determined polymorphically. That is, since a direct call is cheaper, the compiler will use that when it can.

Comment: Student is a base class with a virtual function (GetGrade())

Comment: *"when I tried this, but it didn't happen..."* How exactly did you find that out. Kindly write the steps that you took so that others can reproduce this.

Comment: An implementation is not *required* to use a vtable *at all* (whether a class is polymorphic, or inherits from a polymorphic base) and (for implementations that use vtables) a class without virtual function will not have a vtable anyway.  The standard doesn't specify *how* virtual function calls resolve to the correct (most overloaded) function at runtime - it just requires that they do.   So, if the compiler can (through analysis) determine the actual type of an object, it can call the function directly rather than via the machinery of virtual function dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple case of *devirtualization*, or "calling the correct function without reading the vtable". It is an optimization: the code does the same but faster. The compiler is allowed to perform any optimizations on your code, and many compilers do this.

In this specific case, it's easy (for the compiler) to prove that the runtime type of `my_student` is `Student`: the runtime type is the same as the static type, because it's an object and not a pointer. Even if it was a pointer, it could still do this optimization in the following case:

```
Student* my_student{new Student};
my_student->GetGrade();
```

Here, there is no chance for `*my_student` to have any other type than `Student`. However, if the creation and the usage of the object are not nearby in the code, the optimization can't be performed.

```
Student* my_student{};
if (special)
    my_student = new SpecialStudent;
else
    my_student = new Student;
my_student->GetGrade();
```

Of course, where you really need polymorphism, no devirtualization can be performed. Conversely, if the compiler performs devirtualization, you should think whether you need virtual functions at all.